# Apache Solr XPathEntityProcessor DIH - Index Update

Tags: solr

I am relatively new to Apache SOlr and have recently been working with DIH, specifically the XPathEntityProcessor. I need a way to periodically index new XML files, however, it appears the delta-import command is only supported by the sqlEntityProcessor [1].

I am working with an increasingly large dataset of XML files and was hoping solr could determine new files and index them...

A potential solution that came to mind is to possibly do a full-import from a staging area consisting of documents that have not been previously index, before moving the documents to their respective permanent locations.

1. Is there a workaround to mimicking delte-import using XPathEntityProcessor?
2. What sort of approaches do people using XPathEntityProcessor use to index newer documents?

[1] http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Using_delta-import_command-1

Comment: From what I've gathered so far, I may have to write my own stylesheet for converting input XML files into Solr format and programmatically send result(s) to Solr for indexing... It would have been so much easier if delta-import was implemented natively with XPathEntityProcessor though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resorted to using the UpdateRequestHandler; it's perfect for what I want to do.

[1] http://wiki.apache.org/solr/XsltUpdateRequestHandler